# Is there a forms builder for Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, forms, domain-driven-design

As I have a complex domain model (DDD) where I need to create a few hundred forms in the user interface, I'm looking for a generator, preferably embedding the apple layout rules, and data binding. This is crucial to get a uniform application appearance.

I would prefer the generating to be of run-time instances (introspection), not static source code.

I do not want to build from a data model, as that doesn't have enough information to create something useable. I have information on grouping, validation, roles and rights, navigation, filtering, actions, workflow so I should be able to do much better layouts.

Even better would be the ability to also generate forms for the iPhone/iPad, using the default navigation.

[Results]
Sensible TableViews looks like the right kind of solution for iPhone. The descriptions are not yet sophisticated enough but provide a good starting point.

Comment: Is nobody building business applications for Mac?

Comment: I don't know any tools for this either. But it sounds like a very interesting idea for starting an open-source framework!

Answer (score 8):

Interface Builder will do this for Core Data models if you option-drag parts of (or all of) your data model from the Data Modeler into a window or view in Interface Builder.

When you drop the managed object(s) you dragged, you're given an option to create a Single Item View, a Master/Detail View (with search and detail fields and add/remove buttons), or a Collection View (with box + search field).

I don't know of any third-party solutions to do this from "just any model." It'd be a great tool, but would likely require using an object model to define the entities (like Core Data's Managed Object Model).

Answer (score 1):

[Sensible Tableviews](http://www.sensiblecocoa.com/) Might be able to help you. I haven't used them myself but it looks solid. It also supports generating forms from core data entities.

Comment: I've taken a look at the introduction video's. For iPhone, it looks like the right way.

Comment: Sensible tableviews hasn't been released yet. There's also a http://code.google.com/p/coredatalibrary/ which does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Echasoft Reports](http://etchasoft.com/etchasoftreports.html) would work for your problem? (Plugin for Interface Builder that gives you easier reporting capabilities). I saw this demoed at NSConference, and it looks pretty awesome. Commercial, yes, but for 100+ forms it might be worth the money...

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear, I need them to be in the user interface, not PDF. It's supposed to be a user interface for he domain model

Comment: Ahh. Don't know, might still be helpful, even if it's geared towards printing reports.